# Kendo treelist - trying to set a column template

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm working with a Kendo treelist widget, and disappointed to see there's no `rowTemplate` option as there is on the Kendo grid.

I see a `columnTemplate` option (i.e. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist#configuration-columns.template ), but this will affect the entire column.

However, I need to drill into each cell value and set a css color property based on a ratio ( i.e. If `value/benchmark < .2`, assign `<span style='color:red;'>` , but my color value is dynamic.

There's a `dataBound:` and `dataBinding:` event on the  `treelist`, but I'm still trying to figure out how to intercept each cell value and set the color once I've done my calculation.

```js
var treeOptions = {
dataSource: ds,
columns: colDefs,
selectable: true,
scrollable: true,
resizable: true,
reorderable: true,
height: 320,
change: function (e) {
    // push selected dataItem
    var selectedRow = this.select();
    var row = this.dataItem(selectedRow);                    
},
dataBound: function (e) {
    console.log("dataBinding");
    var ds = e.sender.dataSource.data();
    var rows = e.sender.table.find("tr");
}
};
```

and this is where I'm building out the `colDefs' object (column definitions):

```js
function parseHeatMapColumns(data, dimId) {
// Creates the Column Headers of the heatmap treelist.
// typeId=0 is 1st Dimension; typeId=1 is 2nd Dimension 

var column = [];
column.push({
"field": "field0",
"title": "Dimension",
headerAttributes: { style: "font-weight:" + 'bold' + ";" },
attributes : { style: "font-weight: bold;" }
});

var colIdx = 1;     // start at column 1 to build col headers for the 2nd dimension grouping
_.each(data, function (item) {
if (item.typeId == dimId) {
    // Dimension values are duplicated, so push unique values (i.e. trade types may have dupes, whereas a BkgLocation may not). 
    var found = _.find(column, { field0: item.field0 }); 
    if (found == undefined) {
 column.push({          
     field: "field2",
     title: item.field0,
     headerAttributes: {
  style: "font-weight:" + 'bold'
     }
     ,template: "<span style='color:red;'>#: field2 #</span>"      
 });  
 colIdx++;
    }
}
});

return column;
}
```

**** UPDATE ****
In order to embed some logic within the `template` :

```js
function configureHeatMapColumnDefs(jsonData, cols, model) {
    var colDef = '';
    var dimId = 0;
    var colorProp;

    var columns = kendoGridService.parseHeatMapColumns(jsonData, dimId);

    // iterate columns and set color property; NB: columns[0] is the left-most "Dimension" column, so we start from i=1.
    for (var i = 1; i <= columns.length-1; i++) {
 columns[i]['template'] = function (data) {
     var color = 'black';
     if (data.field2 < 1000) {
  color = 'red';
     }
     else if (data.field2 < 5000) {
  color = 'green';
     }                    
     return "<span style='color:" + color + ";'>" + data.field2 + "</span>";
 };

    }
    return columns;
}
```

Advice is appreciated.
Thanks,
Bob

Comment: This example is for grid but maybe will work for TreeList? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/how-to/cell-color-based-on-foreignkey-values

Comment: Could you please provide data detail which you want to display in treelist?

Comment: @RickS - I've added the `parseHeatMapColumns()` function to my post. This shows how I currently attempt to use the column `template` option; however, I see from the sample you posted that I might want to use a `function` inside the template instead. This way I can calculate the color dynamically. let me try that...

Comment: @JayeshGoyani - file `treedata2.json` is listed here in my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/kXS70zcc8icv3VsUeRw7?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the databound event you can iterate through the rows. For each row you can get the dataItem associated with it using the dataitem() method (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist#methods-dataItem)

Once you have the dataitem, calculate your ration and if the row meets the criteria for color, change the cell DOM element:

```
dataBound: function (e) {
    var that = e.sender;
    var rows = e.sender.table.find("tr");
    rows.each(function(idx, row){
    var dataItem = that.dataItem(row);
    var ageCell = $(row).find("td").eq(2);
    if (dataItem.Age > 30) {
        //mark in red 
         var ageText = ageCell.text();
         ageCell.html('<span style="color:red;">' + ageText + '</span>');                            
    }
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/inoQo)**

**UPDATE:** you can also do this with a template:

```
                $("#treelist").kendoTreeList({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    height: 540,
                    selectable: true,
                    columns: [
                        { field: "Position"},
                        { field: "Name" },
                        { field: "Age",
                         template: "# if ( data.Age > 30  ) { #<span style='color:red;'> #= data.Age # </span>  #}else{# #= data.Age # #}#"
                        }
                    ],

                });
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/uWeqe)**

Comment: that looks like a great alternative to the column `template` option; that is, in the event I cannot get the template option to work for now. I will first experiment with using a function within the column template before going back to the `dataBound` event. thank you.

Comment: @bob, I have updated my answer and demo with a template solution.

Comment: template update: `template: "# if ( data.Age > 30  ) { # <span style='color:red;'> #= data.Age #  #}else{# <span style='color:green;'> #= data.Age # #}#"`

Comment: plunker sample with working treelist. need to add `template` function now... http://plnkr.co/edit/kXS70zcc8icv3VsUeRw7?p=preview

Comment: see my updated plunk, specifically on `field4` in `script.js` http://plnkr.co/edit/kXS70zcc8icv3VsUeRw7?p=preview

Comment: bigger question now is how to change the background-color css on each `<td>` cell. Turns out I don't want to change the text color, but rather the background-color on the <td>. Any ideas ? See script.js in my plunker again http://plnkr.co/edit/kXS70zcc8icv3VsUeRw7?p=preview

Comment: @bob, as you do not have access to the row template and in the column template you cannot access the td, you can go back to the databound method: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/inoQo

Comment: thank you. In conjunction with the `dataBound` event, I'd like to first set the column template dynamically. In http://plnkr.co/edit/kXS70zcc8icv3VsUeRw7?p=preview , and at the bottom of `script.js` I have a for loop to iterate `$scope.options.columns`. But inside `function (data) { }`, how do I know which column I'm currently templating on ? The `data` object contains all columns ?

Comment: I've created a new post re: Kendo grid `rowTemplate`, but I need to figure out how to read the fields at run-time...i.e. `field0` ,.., `field[n]`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789095/kendo-ui-grid-rowtemplate-how-to-make-a-function-call